# Parse.com, Web-app moved to dev server, error 209

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, xampp

I moved my web-app (written in angular) from one dev server to another this morning, and now I get a `400 bad request, error 209 - invalid session token`.

My app reads some info off some parse classes, all classes involved have CLP public get/find set. All rows in my classes have ACL public read set. I am not actively handling any sessions or _User stuff.

Here's an example of what fails. **Worth to note, that this works on my other dev server**, just not on the one I moved to this morning. Both dev servers are XAMPP on Win10, identical configuration.

```
var Menu = Parse.Object.extend('Menu');
var query = new Parse.Query(Menu);
query.ascending('order');
query.equalTo('menu', 'main');
query.find().then(function(results){
    $scope.template.menuObj = results;
}, function(error){
    // error-handling
    console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
});
```

Comment: I have same issue ... I have just cleared the browser local storage ..

Comment: I tried that, doesn't change anything for me...